# Share storybook project accross several Vuejs project

Tags: vue.js, storybook

I want to start to use Storybook on my vueJS application. Since the stories seem to be "attached" to the project, I was wondering if I could use them for other app without duplicating them.
Like, can I have a repository with just stories ? How could it work to import them ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please, provide more details, the question doesn't make sense in general. It's unclear how it's supposed to work. Are there Foo and Bar components in project A and B? What if Foo is missing or in another location? What if stories should differ in some way, like different component props?

Comment: If I have project A, B that use the same buttons for example. I'd like to store the buttons as stories and use them in A, B and all future projects. But as far as I know, the stories are attached to a project, I don't know if I can have a project with only stories that I could use on my project

Comment: What are "the same"? How are they imported? Can you provide the example stories for A and B? Storybook isn't attached to a project, although it's the most common way to use it. But it's attached to specific components in use